# How to solve this system of differential equations?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$\begin{cases}
\dot{p}=-p+2x\\
\dot{x}=\frac{1}{2}p + x\\
\end{cases}$

I don't know how I can express $p$ only in terms of $p$'s or $x$ only in terms of $x$'s. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x=(1/2)(p'+p)$, $x'=(1/2)(p''+p')$, $(1/2)(p''+p')=(1/2)p+(1/2)(p'+p)$.

(edited to correct a typo noted in the comments)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Did you mean $(1/2)(p''+p')=(1/2)p+(1/2)(p'+p)$ (so with a prime on the $p$)?